# Discord.js MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

**[EDIT] THIS IS FIXED**

So, I'm adding a premium remove command, so that I can remove premium from users at any given time. However, I tried it and it responded with this error:

`Discord.js MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]`

How can I fix this?

If more infos are needed, DM me on discord (magma#9950) or comment.

```
await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            await premiumSchema.deleteOne({
                userID: user.id
            }, {
                userID: user.id,
                username: user.username
            }, {
                upsert: true
            })
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.deleteOne()` accepts three parameters; a filter object, an options object, and a callback function. You pass an object as the third parameter (`{ upsert: true }`) and that's why Mongo is complaining that a `callback must be a function, got [object Object]`.

It looks like you just replaced an `updateOne` or `findOneAndUpdate` method with a `deleteOne` and haven't checked the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne) how to use it.

I'm not sure what you're trying to delete. If it's a document with a certain userID, you can use the following:

```js
try {
  await premiumSchema.deleteOne({ userID: user.id });
} finally {
  // ...
}
```